# Rails How to make an simple link hider?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create an simple link hider to hide external links.

I was thinking about creating a controller named Links:

```
class links < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to :(My link column)
  end 
end
```

And my database should be something like this:

```
ID       link
1        http://stackoverflow.com
2        http://google.com
```

Example if I visit links/index/1 i would be redirected to http://stackoverflow.com

How do I redirect to the link that in the link column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Link model doesn't do anything out of the ordinary, you can do something like this...

**controller.rb**

```
def index
  redirect_to Link.find(params[:id]).link
end
```

Comment: Do you now how to set all links that are been redirected to rel nofollow in the robots.txt?

Answer (score 0):

When you visit `links/index/1` you are actually calling the show action (usually) or any other action that you specified such a route for.

What you could is, in your corresponding action,
you could make a `redirect call to the content in the link column for that id (1 in your route params)`.
If you need help with a code sample, let me know. I think its pretty easy to understand the way I said.